# SWITCHOFFSET with table column argument

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetimeoffset

This query works well for specific a argument

```
SELECT 
   [upload_time]
   , SWITCHOFFSET ('05-10-2012 12:00:00 AM', '+05:00') AS datetimeconversion
FROM 
   [mynews_local_db].[dbo].[upload_news]
```

When I modify query like this:

```
 SELECT 
    [upload_time]
    , SWITCHOFFSET ([upload_time], '+05:00') AS datetimeconversion
FROM 
    [mynews_local_db].[dbo].[upload_news]
```

There is error so what I have to do because I have lot of data in table I want display all the data.

Answer (score 2):

Since your current Column value is only Datetime , you will need to convert/cast it to DATETIMEOFFSET before you can use this SWITCHOFFSET expression.

Also if you have a look at the MSDN documentation for [`SWITCHOFFSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb677244(v=sql.105).aspx), the first argument for this expression expects a Datetimeoffset value.

Try this....

```
SELECT [upload_time]
   , SWITCHOFFSET (CAST([upload_time] AS DATETIMEOFFSET), '+05:00') AS datetimeconversion
FROM [mynews_local_db].[dbo].[upload_news]
```